# Use case for `nil`.to_i #=> 0`, `"".to_i #=> 0` `nil`.to_f #=> 0.0`, `"".to_f #=> 0.0`

Tags: ruby, null, integer

I feel it would be natural if `"".to_i` and `"".to_f` were `nil` or raised an exception, and it does not make much sense to me to define `nil.to_i` or `nil.to_f`.

What are the use cases of `nil.to_i #=> 0`, `"".to_i #=> 0`, `nil.to_f #=> 0.0` and `"".to_f #=> 0.0`?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl JavaScript appeared around the same time as Ruby, and I don't think the former affected the latter. It could be from some other languages like C or Perl, though.

Comment: wow.. I always thought Ruby was a few years younger. It seems both langs were born around 1995. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: One simple example: if you have an array `a` of strings and want the element `s`  for which `s.to_i` is the largest positive value: `a.max_by { |s| s.to_i > 0 && s.to_i }`

Comment: @CarySwoveland In such case, I would have `""` or `nil` removed from `a` in advance. That seems semantically better.

Comment: hm.. Isn't this question actually answerable by Yukihiro Matsumoto only? :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl He is available in Ruby mailing list. Not here :)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Unless this is a quirky feature that only he supports.

Comment: So you want to litter your code with a bunch of `nil?` checks rather than saying `x.to_i`? I think you should take this discussion to the Ruby mailing list.

Comment: If someone can come up with the detail of what quetzalcoatl is mentioning in a comment to Makoto's answer, then that might be a good answer.

Comment: @muistooshort If you can show some typical cases when `x.to_i` would be more useful than `nil?`, then that can be a good answer.

Comment: Re `nil.to_i #=> 0`, there is an interesting discussion [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/127973) (especially @phrogz' answer). I think the point is that it's a language decision, balancing off logical design and practical convenience. If different decisions in the past had been made, we obviously could live with them.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think the essence of phrogz' answer is that you can unconditionally do `* 2`. But I can't think of why you would want to do that.

Comment: Do you question the utility of `NilClass#to_a`, `NilClass#to_s`, and `NilClass#to_h` as well? I call the various `to_X` methods all the time to convert `nil` to "empty whatevers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two situations:

1. Starting value.

   ```
   @count = @count.to_i.next
   ```

   as opposed to

   ```
   @count = 0
   @count += 1
   ```
2. Convenience with transformations.

   Often times you get collection returned with some values, which are `nil`. Usually, you want to either remove those or count them as default values.

   Lets say you have a method that is supposed to calculate the average score of the highest rated post of each SO user. `User#highest_rated` will return `nil` if the user has no posts at all:

   ```
   users.map{ |user| user.highest_rated.to_i }.reduce(:+) / users.size
   ```

   This was not the perfect example, but it happens in everyday transformations all the time.

---

Why not raise an exception or return `nil`?

Ruby exceeds at usability. Having to make checks for `nil` values everywhere will look a little clumsy. In fact in a lot of cases when I use these operations it is exactly to make sure `nil` values are transformed to their default counterparts.

Also, there is the expectation that `to_i` (for example) will return an integer. Returning `nil` will be a slight wtf moment.

Comment: In your first example, you are using `to_i` just to turn `nil` into `0`, and that does not look that elegant or readable. I would rather write that as `@count = (@count || 0).next`.

Comment: Regarding your second example, If users do not have posts which the scores are to be based on, then I think it more natural to exclude those users in calculating the average. Or, such users should have the score `0` from the beginning.

Comment: @sawa "you are using `to_i` just to turn `nil` into `0`, and that does not look that elegant". When you start with a premise, you will see only one way. For me chaining methods like that looks more elegant then two values in brackets together and `||`.

Comment: @sawa, you don't exclude them from the average, unless you want a statistic for only active users. The premise was that there is a difference between a user with post with zero scores and one with no posts at all.

Comment: @sawa, do you really want `compact`s and `nil?` checks written all over your code? This behavior is one of those small things that make Ruby so elegant IMHO.

Comment: One design principle I understand is that it is better to standardize any irregularity as early as possible. If there were an array that has some irregular values, I would rather use `compact` or `nil?` checks at earlier stages than rely on `to_i` to be later error proof.

Comment: @sawa, but what if these values are essential in some cases and junk in others. You can't remove the `nil` values at the base then. Also, as I said, the need for `nil` checks usually doesn't come from something you got out of the db or given API call, but from conversions. When you go through 2-3 `map`s of arrays/hashes it is not uncommon to have `nil` values. It just provides better usability that way.